# Populate an unordered queue of pointers to vector elements

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have a data structure that works like an unordered queue and a `vector` filled with objects of `class A`. I want to populate the queue one element at a time (using a push() function) with pointers to each of the objects in the vector.

This implementation needs to:

1. Keep track of the original order of the objects in the vector even as the pointers stored in the queue swap positions in accordance with a comparator and the values of the objects
2. Allow for the continued addition of objects to the vector (again, mindful of order)
3. Allow the objects to be edited according to their original order in the vector without needing to recopy everything to the queue (hence, queue of pointers rather than objects)

I've been beating my head against the wall for several hours now in an attempt to figure this out. Right now I have two solutions that both fail for different reasons.

The first is

```
for(auto i = vector.begin(); i < vector.end(); i++)
{
    queue->push(new A (*i));
}
```

This one worked perfectly until it came time to edit the elements in `vector`, at which point I realized that it seemed to have no effect whatsoever on the values in the queue. Maybe the pointers got decoupled somewhere.

The second is

```
for(A* ptr = vector.data(); ptr <= (vector.data()+vector.size()-1); ptr++)
{
    A** bar = new A*;
    *bar = ptr;
    queue->push(*bar);
}
```

As best I can tell, this one successfully matches up the pointers with objects in `vector`, but for some other reason I can't tell causes a core abortion after doing some additional operations on the queue (pop(), max(), etc).

If anyone out there can offer any advice, I would sincerely appreciate it.

Oh, and before I forget, as much as I would love to use `shared_pointers` or `unique_pointers` or `boost`, I'm limiting this to just the STL and `vector`, `list` and `deque`. No other containers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @NathanOliver: Please at least read the question before asking for a MCVE. Your request doesn't really apply/make sense here.

Comment: @JerryCoffin If the user provided an MCVE then someone might be able to tell them what they did wrong.  And I did read the question and came to the conclusion if we could actually see what was being done then we could help better

Comment: Sorry, I'm kind of new here. Lemme see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 1):

Your first and third requirements can be met with pointers, and the implementation is not difficult. What I advise you to do is to not use `auto` since it will give you an iterator object and converting that to a pointer can be hard.

Regarding your second requirement, it cannot be done since adding things to the vector can trigger a reallocation of memory in order to increase the vector capacity, **unless you know the max number of objects the vector should hold beforehand**. For fulfilling all your requirements then, the best solution is to "link" the objects by using the vector index instead of pointers. This is also way simpler.

But then again, if you remove things from the vector, then you have to update the entire queue. The most flexible solution that will allow you to do pretty much everything is to use lists instead of vectors. But it can have performance impact and you have to ponder before making the choice.

To make it work with vector and pointers, here is what I would do:

```
class A { /* your class here */ };
vector<A> vec;

/* Avoid vector reallocating memory. */
vec.reserve(MAX_NUMBER_OF_OBJECTS);

/* Then, populate the vector. */
/* No need for fully populating it though. */
/* ... */

/* Populate the queue. */
queue<A*> q;
for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++){
  q.push(&vec[i]);
}
```

Comment: I didn't even think of that! Thank you. Assuming I don't have to remove anything from the vector (only add things) I should be fine with "linking" without updating the whole queue?

Comment: Actually if you know beforehand the upper limit of elements the vector must hold you can do it with vecotrs. I will update my answer and also give the code for doing the pointers with vectors thing.

Comment: @proteopneum And yes, lists will be safe even if you remove elements of the list since the list will never reallocate memory.